# Can't get factory or service to be recognized in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Trying to get this factory recognised in my other controllers so i can inject a result object into them.

```
myApp.factory('resultService', function(){

function SampleService() {
this.result = [];
}
});
```

This the the code in my controller with some removed that isn't purpose to the question.

```
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', function($scope, ngAudio, SampleService){ 

    $scope.buttonPressed= function() {
   var tempObj = {};
       tempObj.title = $scope.title;
       tempObj.frequency = $scope.frequency; 
console.log(tempObj);

        SampleService.result.push($scope.tempObj);
} 
}]);
```

I keep receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined.

i understand its probably something silly i've missed.

Comment: You don't have `SampleService` in the list of dependencies

Comment: your service needs to return the function you want to use in dependencies ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', function($scope, ngAudio, SampleService){
```

You've nt injected `SampleService` in the array notation of dependencies.

```
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', 'resultService', function($scope, ngAudio, resultService){
```

Also you need to return an object from the `factory`. Currently you're not returning anything.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/unpr?p0=SampleServiceProvider%20%3C-%20SampleService%20%3C-%20125Zero

Comment: Your service name is `resultService` not `SampleService`. So you must refer it via `resultService`

Comment: Thanks, due to my stupidity i got it working now, totally missing the simple problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do somethin like this:

```
myApp.factory('SampleService', function() {
    return {
        result: []
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped alot with tidying up my factory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused

This is your service

```
myApp.factory('resultService', function(){
    this.result = [];
    return this;
});
```

And you can use it in this way

```
myApp.controller('125Zero', ['$scope','ngAudio', 'resultService', function($scope, ngAudio, SampleService, resultService){ 
    $scope.buttonPressed= function() {
        var tempObj = {};
       tempObj.title = $scope.title;
       tempObj.frequency = $scope.frequency; 
       console.log(tempObj);

       resultService.result.push($scope.tempObj);
    } 
}]);
```